# How do i change whole Html page while running on mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a website running on desktop very well.

But when I resize it to mobile resolution it going crazy. And I want to make another new html file(it's whole different design) and make it for only specific resulotions.

But I have stuck with the question how do i do that?.
I make research and found some answers to help me but couldn't figure it out.
I tried hiding the body when they run website on mobile with

```
@media only screen 
    and (max-device-width : 667px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
{
    #body-mobile{
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #body-pc{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

but there is a mistake that i cant create 2 bodies on same html.
So is there any way to make another html or any another way to do it?

Comment: You can use a <div> and wrap it around your content, you can have only 1 <body> but you can have <body><div id="body-mobile"></div><div id="body-pc"></div></body>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
.desktop_container {
  display: block;
}

.mobile_container {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 667px) {
  .desktop_container {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile_container {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="desktop_container">
    <div>Desktop</div>
    <!-- PUT ALL DESKTOP CONTENT HERE -->
  </div>
  <div class="mobile_container">
    <div>Mobile</div>
    <!-- PUT ALL MOBILE CONTENT HERE -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having two `<body>`, you can have `<body><div id="body-mobile"></div><div id="body-pc"></div>`.

Usually all you want to check is `max-width`:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="body-mobile">...</div>
         <div id="body-pc">...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

I would suggest using e.g. [Bootstrap CSS framework](https://getbootstrap.com/) for easier responsive integration:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="d-block d-sm-none">...</div>
         <div class="d-lg-none d-xl-block">...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```